# Combining dataframes in Python that have been uploaded via URL

Tags: python, dataframe

As the title suggests, I am struggling to combine .csv files in Python.

Right now, I have 7 datasets loaded into a Google Colab sheet. I've uploaded them using a url from the desired website, and using `data.head()` I get this as a preview:

```
                     profile_id latitude    longitude   depth   temperature salinity density
time                            
2017-09-06 17:02:10+00:00   725 40.029292   -70.884025  3.21    22.3441 34.898510   1024.0579
2017-09-06 17:02:10+00:00   725 40.029292   -70.884025  4.05    22.3296 34.897360   1024.0647
2017-09-06 17:02:10+00:00   725 40.029292   -70.884025  4.95    22.3297 34.898150   1024.0692
2017-09-06 17:11:29+00:00   726 40.028392   -70.883934  4.96    22.3905 34.886158   1024.0428
2017-09-06 17:11:29+00:00   726 40.028392   -70.883934  4.18    22.4317 34.871895   1024.0170
```

With 7 datasets structured in this fashion, and uploaded via a url, how would I go about combining them into one dataset in python?

Edit:
They are read in as such:

```
data1 = pd.read_csv(url, skiprows=[1], parse_dates=['time'], index_col='time')
data2 = pd.read_csv(url2, skiprows=[1], parse_dates=['time'], index_col='time')
data3 = pd.read_csv(url3, skiprows=[1], parse_dates=['time'], index_col='time')
data4 = pd.read_csv(url4, skiprows=[1], parse_dates=['time'], index_col='time')
data5 = pd.read_csv(url5, skiprows=[1], parse_dates=['time'], index_col='time')
data6 = pd.read_csv(url6, skiprows=[1], parse_dates=['time'], index_col='time')
data7 = pd.read_csv(url7, skiprows=[1], parse_dates=['time'], index_col='time')
```

Comment: So all 7 datasets are stored in `pandas` dataframes analogical to `data`, right?

Comment: yes, I just edited the question to update how I stored them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
combined_df = pd.concat([data1, data2, data3, data4, data5, data6, data7], axis=0)
```